# Почему f-строки используют редко?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Изучаю Python не так давно. Бывает, что рассматриваю чужой код и заметил такую тенденцию, что f-строки используют намного реже, чем `str.format()`. Стало интересно с чем это связано, ведь f-строки объективно намного проще для написания и восприятия. Дело в привычке или, может, обратной совместимости с версиями ниже 3.6?

Comment: Многие начинали с других версий и еще не привыкли. Я начинал с 2.7, но уже привык :)

Comment: В таком случае, использование f-строк не является плохой практикой? А то у меня начали закрадываться сомнения :)

Comment: https://python-scripts.com/f-strings

Comment: Использование f-строк является хорошей практикой (ИМХО).

Comment: Я начинал с 1.4, и **абсолютно** не могу пользоваться `format`. Только `%`, только олдскул!

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#rationale

Comment: @Pak Uula Лучше переходите на 3.7 и юзайте f""

Comment: @Victor says Reinstate Monica, уже давно) но когда нужно что-то распечатать, руки автоматически ставят %

Comment: К прочтению: [Холиварный рассказ про линтеры](https://habr.com/ru/company/oleg-bunin/blog/433480/), раздел "F-строки ужасны?"

Comment: Как по мне, это чисто исторический фактор. Раньше все форматировали через '%', затем появился .format, теперь пришло время f-строк. Я лично люблю(привык) .format, но f-строки тоже потихоньку ввожу в использование.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PEP498:

> F-strings provide a concise, readable way to include the value of Python expressions inside strings.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#rationale

Соответственно использовать f-строки хорошо.

Comment: Что-то я не нашел там такого. В каком разделе?

Comment: @Эникейщик здесь: python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#rationale

Comment: @Leetovskiy это совсем не 8 :)

Comment: @Эникейщик Ну да, это не pep8, а как тогда пометить?

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica pep-498, там же написано :)

Comment: @Эникейщик А точно...

Answer (score 1):

3 основные вещи о f-строках:

1. Они работают БЫСТРЕЕ
2. Читабельные код, меньше строк
3. Фичи для отладки

Не используют, так как многие писали код для более ранних версий, и даже сейчас многие системы на ранних версиях. А переписывать рабочий и не проблемный код, это явно не эффективно.